# Replace value using REGEX with Groovy and SED

Tags: regex, linux, shell, groovy, sed

I have an XML file that contains a "Description" property. I would like to replace the contents of that property with a different description. I am using a SED command within a Groovy script

```
<VisualElements Description="foo" Title="title"/>
```

I tried the following line, but it does not replace the value of the "Description" value with the string "bar".

```
def sedCommand = 'sed -i \'s/Description="([^"]*)"/Description="bar"/g\'  package.appxmanifest' as String
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the above line?

Update: based on Wiktor Stribiżew's comment below, I have updated the command to reflect the latest error

Comment: What if you remove `\(` and `\)`? Or try doubling the backslashes there: `\(` -> `\\(`, `\)` -> `\\)`. Also, you might want to use `-i.bak` instead of `-i`.

Comment: Why are you using sed? Just use groovy...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your suggestion removed the "unexpected character" error. However, it still doesn't replace the contents of the "Description" property with the "bar" value. I will update the original post.

Comment: The `(` and `)` in the BRE regex match literal `(` and `)`. Remove them altogether.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks. that did it!

Comment: One more question! Which may require a new question. Instead of using "bar" as a value, I use Description="${variableName}". The problem with this is that instead of the variable replacing the value, the string "${variableName}" is used. How do I escape it so the variable value is used to replace the property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *sed* with a BRE regex (i.e. no `-E` or `-r` options), so your `(` and `)` are parsed as *literal* parentheses, not a grouping construct. Anyway, you are not using backreferences and replacing the whole match, there is no point keeping the parentheses at all:

```
def sedCommand = 'sed -i \'s/Description="[^"]*"/Description="bar"/g\'  package.appxmanifest' as String
                                          ^^^^^
```

will work well.

If you need to use variables, see [*How do I use variables in a sed command?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command)

The sed command will look as

```
#!/bin/bash
foo="hello"
echo '<VisualElements Description="foo" Title="title"/>' | \
 sed 's/Description="[^"]*"/Description="'$foo'"/g'
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/bWUJf5).

Comment: Removing the parenthesis works, but I'm still having issues with the variable. I am using groovy AND sed so it's not as clear cut how to use a variable as it is when just using sed.